# Замена текста при изменении разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы текст заменялся другим при изменении разрешения экрана посредством css?

Comment: По-видимому, вы ошиблись, у экрана есть **«разрешение»**

Comment: для этого используйте @media screen - пример http://jsfiddle.net/yy3t17uz/

Comment: Да, верно, ошибся) спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

html:

```
<div class="for-small-screens">Текст для маленьких экранов</div>
<div class="for-large-screens">Текст для больших экранов</div>
```

css:

```
@media(max-width:960px) {
  .for-large-screens {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media(min-width:961px) {
  .for-small-screens {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: И увидите прикол при ширине 960px ;)

Comment: Угу, спасибо, поправил (`min-width: 960px` → `min-width: 961px`)!

Answer (score 1):

Например при помощи псевдоклассов, свойства `content` и @media screen. Выполнить код расположенный в ответе надо на всю страницу, что бы увидеть результат.

```css
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
p:before {
  content: "large screen";
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  p:before {
    content: "small screen";
  }
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Можно ещё позабавиться и брать значения из data-атрибутов. Текст всегда проще писать в html)

Comment: @Rolandius смотря для каких целей. Не могу согласится с вами полностью, например если текст относится к статичному оформлению сайта

Comment: Поэтому я и написал, что текст )

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width:350px) {
    .object {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]